# perl printing remaining list in array

Tags: arrays, perl

Please let me know where and what I am doing wrong ... I simply want to print the list one by one after removing element from an array.

```
my $n = {};
my @current_list;
my @current_listremove;
@current_list = eval { $Table->invoke("get"); };

for ($n=0; $n < $size; $n++) {
    my $currentIP=$current_list[$n][0];
    if ( $MngtIP eq $currentIP ) {
        # --- > I am able to get correct output below
        DEBUG("DEBUG : Management IP $MngtIP exists in current list"); 

        # --- > Here I am deleting the ip which matches    
        @current_listremove = delete $current_list[$currentIP];  
    }
}

 # --- > Here I am trying to print the remaining list in array
 my $updatedIP = $current_listremove[0][0]; 
 my $size = @current_listremove;
 for ($n=0; $n < $size; $n++) {
     my $currentIP1=$current_listremove[$n][0];
     DEBUG("DEBUG : Management IP updated list $currentIP1");   }
```

Expected output :

```
IP address in new list 
100.100.100.1  -- if this Matched then remaining 4 should show in updated list   
100.100.100.2
100.100.100.3
100.100.100.4
100.100.100.5
```

Thanks

---

For better understanding below is the input to array `@current_list = $Table->invoke('get')`

Output looks like :

```
Intable data is stored in below format
{
 {
   100.100.100.1
   Device1|Location1

 }
 {
   100.100.100.2
   Device2|Location2
 }
 {
   100.100.100.3
   Device3|Location3
 }
 {
   100.100.100.4
   Device4|Location4
 }
}
```

I am able to correctly display below output

```
for ($n=0; $n < $size; $n++) {
    $currentIP=@current_list[$n][0]
    DEBUG("DEBUG : Current IP $currentIP exists in current list");
}
```

Output looks like

```
100.100.100.1
100.100.100.2
100.100.100.3
100.100.100.4
```

MngtIP ---> we are getting from latest data file 
For example MngtIP is 100.100.100.1  now I am able to get the output that "DEBUG : Management IP 100.100.100.1 exists in current list" but after that unable to delete and print the remaining list

---

Dumper Output :

```
$VAR1 = [
          '100.100.100.1',
          'Device1|India|324|HP|AA|JPJ|Delhi',
          'Device1',
          '',
          '',
          ''
        ];
$VAR2 = [
          '100.100.100.2',
          'Device2|London|564|HP|BB|PLP|Pune',
          'Device2',
          '',
          '',
          ''
        ];
$VAR3 = [
          '100.100.100.3',
          'Device3|Australia|989|HP|CC|MNM|Chennai',
          'Device3',
          '',
          '',
          ''
        ];
$VAR4 = [
          '100.100.100.4',
          'Device4|China|009|HP|DD|BHB|jaipur',
          'Device4',
          '',
          '',
          ''
        ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you have an array of arrays, and the IP addresses are the first element of the inner arrays.

I think what you need is this. It copies `@current_list`  to `@current_list_remove`, removes the element that has an IP address matching `$MngtIP`, and then prints out the list of remaining IPs.

The main problem was that you are trying to `delete $current_list[$currentIP]` which uses an IP address string to index an array. That isn't going to work.

*Please* add `use strict` and `use warnings` to the top of every program that you write. That simple measure would have alerted you to this mistake straight away.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($Table, $MngtIP);

my @current_list = eval { $Table->invoke("get"); };

my @current_listremove = grep { $_->[0] ne $MngtIP } @current_list;

for my $item (@current_listremove) {
  my $ip = $item->[0];
  print "$ip\n";
}
```

---

**Update**

Here's a demonstration of the solution above using your posted data, showing that it works as described

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @current_list = (
  [ '100.100.100.1', 'Device1|India|324|HP|AA|JPJ|Delhi',       'Device1', '', '', '', ],
  [ '100.100.100.2', 'Device2|London|564|HP|BB|PLP|Pune',       'Device2', '', '', '', ],
  [ '100.100.100.3', 'Device3|Australia|989|HP|CC|MNM|Chennai', 'Device3', '', '', '', ],
  [ '100.100.100.4', 'Device4|China|009|HP|DD|BHB|jaipur',      'Device4', '', '', '', ],
);

my $MngtIP = '100.100.100.3';

my @current_listremove = grep { $_->[0] ne $MngtIP } @current_list;

for my $item (@current_listremove) {
  my $ip = $item->[0];
  print "$ip\n";
}
```

**output**

```
100.100.100.1
100.100.100.2
100.100.100.4
```

Comment: Thank you so much Borodin .. Now What I can see first the Ip gets removed but it comes back again next round ... I mean as shown by you firstly 100.100.100.3 gets removed and then the output is as shown by you  but now when next Ip comes for example 100.100.100.2 now the list should print 100.100.100.1 and 100.100.100.4 but it's printing 100.100.100.3 as well. Which means it's correctly remoivng the ip and displaying rest but that Ip again comes when an other ip gets removed.

Comment: @user3717017: The `@current_listremove` list is left unchanged. The modified list is in `@current_listremove`

Comment: Thanks for the response .. Do you mean array current_list is left unchanged and we are printing values of array current_listremove. Actually my script is reading data 1 by one and the output should be reduced ...like first 100.100.100.1,100.100.100.2 & 100.100.100.4 ..second 100.100.100.1 & 100.100.100.2. but it's printing 100.100.100.3 which was deleted in 1st loop.

Comment: @user3717017: Yes, I'm sorry for the typing mistake. The `@current_list` array doesn't change, so you'll just be creating a new `@current_listremove` each time with a different IP address missing. The original question you posted has been answered, so you need to ask a new question if you need to after spending some time on it yourself